# How could I block specific sub pages and not just domains (HTTP and HTTPS)?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, blocking

So I am trying to make something that will block specific urls on my computer, not just an entire domain. For example, i'd like to block specific subreddits.

With HTTP this is pretty easy - I make a proxy and route traffic through it, but with HTTPS I do not get access to the subpage with this method.

Is there another way I could block it via a proxy or a VPN of some sort?

Any ideas would be helpful but I prefer not to do it through a chrome extension or something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/391056/how-to-block-specific-https-traffic

Comment: Also, I recommend reading [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/48086/52297)